# Store jsonobject in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I have a `contact` `JsonArray` inside a json file. Here is the structure

```
"contact": [
            {
                "ref": [
                    1
                ], 
                "corresponding": true, 
                "name": "XYZ"
            }, 
            {
                "ref": [
                    1
                ], 
                "name": "ZXY"
            }, 
            {
                "ref": [
                    1
                ], 
                "name": "ABC"
            }, 
            {
                "ref": [
                    1, 
                    2
                ], 
                "name":"BCA"
            }
        ]
```

Now, I have a 4 contacts array like this one, which have multiple names.I want to store all the `name` in a ArrayList to show in `customListview`.

Now my question is

1) What is the recommended approach store this data and retrieve data ?

2) How can I store only `name` in an `ArrayList<JsonObject>`?

3) is my 2nd choice is a good or recommended approach??

Comment: Want to store `name` and still JSONObject? Instead you can just take `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: Do you know JSON Parsing in Android?

Comment: @PareshMayani Yes, I Tried with  ArrayList<String>. But, when I tried to retrieve like name.get(0), it returns only "XYZ". But I want to store all 4 names in same index. That's why I thought to use ArrayList<JsonObject>

Comment: same index? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: @PareshMayani  Yes, I have another object called topic and topic was proposed by these contacts. So, in the Custom Listview I have to show topic name and contacts name.

Comment: they why are you not taking ArrayList<JSONObject> where every JSONObject will have name, ref, contact or whatever you want. Later you can fetch any object by its position.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a java bean `Contact` and the `ArrayList<Contact>`

Comment: Why to create a class if we can have JSONObject and can store in ArrayList<JSONObject>?

Comment: Yeah. But you have to extract the value from it whenever you need it. Its basically, your preference.